# Java-8 - replacing "?" character from the start of a Optional.of(String)

Tags: java, string, java-8, option-type

I'm trying to replace "?" character or delete it if my string start with `?`. I tested this code and it doesn't work:

```
Optional<String> stringvalue = Optional.of("?test1=search&test2=ok&test3=hello");

String parameterName = "test1";

if( stringvalue.get().startsWith("?") ){
    stringvalue.get().replaceFirst("\\?", "");
}
System.out.println(stringvalue.get());
```

Comment: you've ignored the result of `replaceFirst`. Strings are immutable. each attempt to modify it will result in a new string object with the modifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Optional.map` as well:

`stringvalue = stringvalue.map( (s) -> s.startsWith("?") ? s.replaceFirst("\\?", "") : s );`

Comment: As a side note, `s.substring(1)` is a much simpler and more efficient way to remove the first character than `s.replaceFirst("\\?", "")`. Unless you use `s.replaceFirst("^\\?", "")` to get rid of the conditional.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the comment of [@Aominè](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176436/replacing-character-in-a-string-that-start-with-it-using-java-8#comment83332764_48176436) **but how?** I think you have to use :

```
if (stringvalue.get().startsWith("?")) {
    stringvalue = Optional.of(stringvalue.get().replaceFirst("\\?", ""));
    //            ^^^^^^^^^^^-------note this
}
```

Or just :

```
stringvalue = Optional.of(stringvalue.get().replaceFirst("^\\?", ""));
//------------^^^^^^^^^^^---------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are [immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) in Java. So `stringvalue.get().replaceFirst("\\?", "");` leaves the original String value unchanged. You need to store the result of the replacement like this:

```
String parameterName = stringvalue.get().replaceFirst("\\?", "");
```

Also note that you can use `^` avoiding to test if the string startsWith `?`:

```
String parameterName = stringvalue.get().replaceFirst("^\\?", "");
```